# Load application context without using web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was wondering if there's a way to Load Springs application context without having to define it in a *web.xml*.

I see you can use:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

But if you wanted to use a bean you've got to **getBean()** to have access to it. I am thinking possibly there could be a way to load the context programmatically as would the definition in web xml, without having to call getBean.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(this,
                  AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
```

...where ctx is your ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to avoid the need to ever call getBean() - any spring bean fields on `this` will be autowired for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. You just have to read official documentation. The relevant part is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-web-configuration).

**Edit**: Sorry, misread your question. You can use

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

and load it using `ServletContextListener` at application startup. When your application starts, if you've configured your bean wiring properly, you shouldn't have to call **getBean()** to access all of your beans. Treat it like you're using Java SE.

Comment: I don't see anything in that part that works *without having to define it in a web.xml*

Comment: You mean all i need is the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext instantiation in a ServletContextListener and it will do the the rest for me?

Comment: @Bitmap: almost. You'll still need to use **getBean()** for "top-level" beans that are in your wiring hierarchy. The rule is: if you use the "new" keyword for creation of beans, they won't be wired using Spring. If you make a static public getter for app. context in ServletContextListener, you can get your beans pretty effortlessly when you need to do.

Comment: Could've done it neatly the way the web.xml does it - I am experimenting that instead. Reason been I never want to call getBean.

Comment: @Bitmap: I don't think it's possible; you'll probably need to call getBean at least once.